# OpeningRestful API ends with 404 allt the time

Tags: java, rest, api, jersey, jax-rs

I have a done MVC Java project and I need to make an API for it. I'm trying to use Jersey. I installed it according to this instruction:
http://www.mazong1123.com/use-jersey-2.0-without-maven/
Since my project was already done and it was not a maven. Also, I'm following this instruction: http://www.mazong1123.com/use-jersey-2.0-without-maven/

The thing is I've downloaded and put all.jar files into my project WEB-INF, then I created RESTful Web Services from Patterns (created class within my package where the model, servlet, and .jdbc are. After that `BookResource.java` and `ApplicationConfig.java` were created as on the screen:

[image]

and edited my web.xml to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" id="WebApp_ID" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" 
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <display-name>parking-space-booking-system</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>PBS</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.pbs.web.jdbc</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>PBS</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I'm using Tomcat server. Whenever I provide following URL: `http://localhost:8084/PBS/webapi/booksresource` I'm getting 404. Is it something wrong with my web.xml?

Regards

Comment: Remove PBS and then try.

Comment: PBS from both <servlet-name>? What shall I put there then, or left empty?

Comment: http://localhost:8084/webapi/booksresource

Comment: Server was able to take the request. But it didn't find where that endpoint is. hence it returned 404.

Comment: Share your resource class. Have you mapped them correctly?